# How to write query sql for oracle properly in this case the else statement doesn't working

Tags: php, sql, oracle

i still looking for how to write sql in oracle properly. My goals is display name(NAMA) based on NIK. and if the NIK data not match with the database then else statement executed. right now the else statement not working.

This is my database

| NIK | NAMA |
| --- | --- |
| 94878 | Alfian U |
| 98345 | Galeh S |

Postman response when NIK data match with database

```
[{"NAMA":"Galeh S"}]
```

But when NIK not match with database, else statement doesn't work. Postman response like this

```
[]
```

PHP file.

```
<?php
include ("koneksi.php");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $NIK = $_POST["NIK"];
    $query = "SELECT NAMA FROM MASTER_KRY WHERE NIK = '$NIK'";
    $eksekusi = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    $cek = oci_execute($eksekusi);
    
    if($cek > 0){
        $response = array();
        while($ambil = oci_fetch_object($eksekusi)){
            $F["NAMA"] = $ambil->NAMA;
            array_push($response, $F);
        }
        } else {
            $response = "Data not available";
        }
}
else{
    $response = "Response Error";
}
echo json_encode($response);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: You won't reach the (first) else; `oci_execute` returns true/false, not the number of rows that were found. You would need to track whether any fetch returned anything; or check if the array is still empty after the while loop?

Comment: **NEVER** use un-sanitised user input directly to build a query via template strings. If you want to pass it as a parameter to a query then use a parameterised query and a bind variable. Otherwise someone is going to pass `' OR 'A' = 'A` to your script ([or worse](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/252475/261465)).